# App Android com fundo colorido em botões e texto

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Andei a mexer numa app android, e não sei como começou a dar problemas...não iniciava de todo, assim que abria aparecia a mensagem a dizer que a app crachou e se queria reinicia-la. Depois de algum esforço para perceber o que se passava, descobri que algo se passou com o tema, então andei a trocar o `theme` no manifest, o resultado deu num background vermelho em quase toda a app, como posso resolver isso? Que propriedades tenho de alterar? Veja uma screenshot da app:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os itens que estão a vermelho têm a propriedade `background` em vermelho..eu sei que antes não estava a exibir vermelho e sei que não andei a trocar a cor do fundo, estou confuso.

Está aqui o xml do `style` que uso:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/burning_gold</item>
    </style>
<style name="ActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/ccilc_red</item>
</style>
```

Comment: você pode editar e colocar o layout dessa tela da print?, só pra eu confirmar o que é..

Comment: Ja descobri o problema, era isto `<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>`, descobri usando versões mais antigas do mesmo app e vendo as diferenças que havia no XML.

Comment: beleza então, ...